# Json data object: how to concatenate string (message) only if previous message was sent by same user?

Tags: json, python-3.x, string, parsing

I have been lately trying to parse a json file with some data in it. Data in the following structure:

```
{
"participants": [
  {"name": "Lana"},
  {"name": "Adam"}],
"messages": [
  { "sender_name": "Adam", "timestamp_ms": 1579638034407, "content": "love you", "type": "Generic"},
  {"sender_name": "Lana","timestamp_ms": 1579634379711,"content": "love you too, baby","type": "Generic"},
  {"sender_name": "Adam","timestamp_ms": 1579634359503,"content": "Thanks again baby","type": "Generic"},
  { "sender_name": "Adam", "timestamp_ms": 1579638034407, "content": "see you very soon", "type": "Generic"},
  {"sender_name": "Adam","timestamp_ms": 1579634379711,"content": "have fun","type": "Generic"},
  {"sender_name": "Lana","timestamp_ms": 1579634359503,"content": "you too love","type": "Generic"},
  { "sender_name": "Adam", "timestamp_ms": 1579638034407, "content": "bye bye", "type": "Generic"},
  {"sender_name": "Lana","timestamp_ms": 1579634379711,"content": "Im already missing you","type": "Generic"},
  {"sender_name": "Adam","timestamp_ms": 1579634359503,"content": "me too","type": "Generic"},
 ]
}
```

What Im trying to get is the following:

```
0 None
1 love you
2 love you too, honey
5 Thanks again baby . see you very soon . have fun
6 you too, love
7 bye bye
```

What I'm getting instead:

```
0 love you
1 love you too, baby
2 Thanks again baby
3 Thanks again baby . see you very soon
4 Thanks again baby . see you very soon . have fun
5 you too, love
6 bye bye
```

The code I use to parse the Json object:

```
def parse_json(file_obj):
    previous_participant = None
    previous_message = None
    for i, m in enumerate(file_obj['messages']):
        if 'content' in m:
            if previous_participant == m['sender_name'] and previous_message != None:
                previous_message = previous_message +" . "+ m['content']
            else:
                previous_participant = m['sender_name']
                previous_message = m['content']
            print(i, previous_message)
        pass


parse_json(xy)
```

if a user sends more then one message in a row it keeps returning each previous message + the current one. I know I'm doing it wrong, and i don't yet seem to have figured it out. Very much appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: I have employed a list object to hold the messages, I have tried to avoid that for performance reasons, but I cannot think of a better option.

Here is the code now:

```
def parse_json(file_obj):
    previous_participant = None
    previous_message = None
    chat = []
    for i, m in enumerate(file_obj['messages']):
        if 'content' in m:
            if previous_participant == m['sender_name'] and previous_message != None:
                previous_message = previous_message +" . "+ m['content']
            else:
                chat.append(previous_message)
                previous_participant = m['sender_name']
                previous_message = m['content']
        pass
    print(i, chat)
```

Not so efficient but works for now. Thank you.

Comment: You expected  output doesn't appear to match the data  in your JSON. What happened to 3 & 4? Where is the `Im already missing you`?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a short, sweet way to do it with your numbering schema. If you get rid of those numbers you can remove the entire `for` loop at  the end of this  code. That being said this appears to get your output. Though I don't understand what happened to output 3 & 4 in your expected output.

```
def get_messages_by_name(data):
    # An endless cycle of participants
    participants = cycle(d['name'] for d in data['participants'])

    # Pull out the names and messages  from the JSON
    messages = [(d['sender_name'], d['content']) for d in data['messages']]

    #  Group the messages by the sender name.
    messages_per_sender = [
      (grouped_by_name, ', '.join([tup[1] for tup in tups]))
          for grouped_by_name, tups in 
              groupby(messages, lambda m: m[0])
    ]

    # Now  we need to do the numbering.
    result = []
    for message_name, message in messages_per_sender:
        current_name = next(participants)
        while current_name != message_name:
            result.append(None)
            current_name = next(participants)
        result.append(message)

    for index, message in enumerate(result):
        print(index, message)
```

Output:

```
0 None
1 love you
2 love you too, baby
3 Thanks again baby, see you very soon, have fun
4 you too love
5 bye bye
6 Im already missing you
7 me too
```